# Boolean attributes not displaying any options when used as part of conditions or actions in a promo rule

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, promotions

I've got a couple of boolean custom attributes which I'm having an issue using in cart or catalog price rules. These attributes appear correctly on the product edit pages and can be used successfully for criteria in advanced search. The problem occurs when trying to use these attributes as part of promo rules. The attributes show up properly as options to be used for conditions or actions, but when selected, the drop-down is empty and does not let me pick if the attribute should be true/false:
[image: Select has no options]
This is the setup for one of the attributes in the admin section:
[image: Storefront Properties]
and the code used to generate the attribute:

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'gtr',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Guaranteed to Run',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'configurable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => '',
            'is_used_for_promo_rules' => true,
            'is_used_for_price_rules' => true
        ]
    );
```

Can anyone lend any insight into why this is happening?